# Having trouble while integrating startapp into my app

Tags: jar, integrate, libs, startapp

I am trying to integrate startapp ads into my application. I am using the guide provided by Startapp. It is given in the following.

**------**start of Guide*** -----*

Step 1: Add the SDK JARs to your Eclipse project

Step 2: Update your manifest file

Step 3: Initialize the SDK

Step 4: Show Banners

Step 5: Show Interstitial Ads

Step 6: Show Splash Ad

**------ **/ end of Guide*** -------*

**In step 1:** I just copied given jar files by Startapp and pasted them into **libs** folder. Then I cleaned the project to update its directories.

**In step 2:** firstly, I added some permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
//These permissions are only required for showing the ad when pressing the Home button:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

secondly, I added new activities under **application** tag by replacing package_name with my app's package name:

```
    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.eula.EULAActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />

<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
android:taskAffinity="<package_name>.AppWall"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
android:taskAffinity="<package_name>.AppWall"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

**In step 3:** In the OnCreate method of my activity, I called the static functions:

```
StartAppAd.init(this, "<Your Developer Id>", "<Your App ID>");
StartAppSearch.init(this, "<Your Developer Id>", "<Your App ID>");
```

I changed app id and developer id according to my account.

After all these 3 steps I got the following two errors from eclipse:

**errors:**

StartAppAd cannot be resolved

StartAppSearch cannot be resolved

I read some docs and answers from some forums but none of them worked. Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import StartAppAd and StartAppSearch.

Add the following imports to your activity:

```
import com.searchboxsdk.android.StartAppSearch;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;
```